# Rails: model setup for school charges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I know this is supposed to be simple but I'm having trouble coming up with a good, simple setup.

I'm building an app for a school. The school charges for things like pre-registration fee, supply fees, monthly enrollment, etc.

The most important aspect of billing is the monthly enrollment. Let's say it's $50 per month. I want to setup recurring billing (maybe with Stripe), but some people might choose to pay cash, or check or one-time credit card charge, instead of an automatic monthly withdrawal from their account.

Also, fees other than monthly enrollment, such as supply fees, books and such.

I was thinking about creating an Invoice setup, which I already have from another app (kinda like Freshbooks or Blinksale, [Item, LineItem, Tax, Invoice, Payment, etc]) but I thought that might be overkill.

So how would you set this up? Important points...

- Ability to charge a monthly recurring fee and other one time charges
- Able to track if item is due or if it has been paid
- Track if monthly enrollment has been paid, MAKING A RELATIONSHIP between the payment and the monthly enrollment

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a payments model. It would have a frequency (monthly, quarterly, half-yearly, yearly), payment status(paid or pending) and due date and type of fee(pre-registration, supply, etc)

If a guy opts one time payment in beginning, he would have all payments inserted and due date would be the current date and all the statuses would be paid.

If he opts for some fees to be paid monthly, he will have 12 records in payment table with frequency 'monthly'. The due date would be spaced one month apart each. The status of the last 11 records would be pending.

You can now track the list of payments whose due date is within next one month and take appropriate action.